# Generated resources directory JetBrains PhpStorm and WebStorm

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

Is it possible to mark a directory as generated, so it will be excluded in the search indexing, but still uploads files automatically to an FTP when changed?

**More specific:** In my project I have a `src` and a `dist` folder, so while working in `src` I don't need any file suggestions for `dist` files in the search. Marking the directory as 'excluded' seems to work, but then it does not  upload external changes to the FTP anymore when compiling the code (using webpack/gulp/babel). So now I need to upload everything manually on each change.

The reason I need to exclude the dist folder is because not all files in there are minified, and I sometimes find myself working in dist without noticing, because they're so similar.

Is there a way to get a combination of both features?

Comment: BTW -- what IDE version do you use? If stable (2016.3.x) -- maybe try 2017.1 EAP build -- they may have some improvements in this area (especially since this seems to be about JavaScript/TypeScript ecosystem (AngularJS/React/etc) -- devs should foresee such typical scenario and should have some other (hard coded?) means for such cases). My answer below is a general answer (not linked to any particular case/technology) but specific case may already has some built-in solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to get a combination of both features?

AFAIK -- Not really.

You can mark files as Plain Text in your `dist` folder .. but it will have to be done on per file basis (which is a real PIA if you need to do this for lots of files or often)...

For JavaScript files you may try adding them as [JavaScript Library files](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.3/configuring-javascript-libraries.html?search=lib).

Otherwise -- only mark such folder(s) as Excluded. Not sure about automatic upload ... but manually invoking `Deployment | Synchronize with Deployed...` works (which you may be using anyway).

---

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-4253
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-12345

Watch these and related tickets (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.

Check all the comments in those tickets as well -- maybe you will find better/working-good-enough workarounds there.